# Python - Pyinstaller: Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have a script that I am trying to convert into an exe file using pyinstaller.
It is saved in C:\Python37\Scripts

But when I try to use the following in the cmd window:

pyinstaller MisfirePlots_v0.py, I get an Invalid Syntax error.

[image: pyinstaller error]

Now I am not sure if this is a pyinstaller issue, or Python issue, or an issue with the script.
The script works fine in Jupyter Lab.

Pyinstaller version is 4.0 and Python version is 3.7

Please help.

Thank you
R

Comment: What's on line 409 of `MisfirePlots_v0.py`. In the future, please do not post images of text

Comment: I should have checked. Good point. I had some unused cells in Jupyter Notebook. They had some erroneous code lines in them. When I saved the script I think these were also saved in the script and hence was causing this issue. It is resolved now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this syntax error has to to with your python script. Please check line 409 in your script again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when running the `pyinstaller --onefile` command, **it's possible that you're running the command in the Python interpreter instead of the command prompt or terminal. The `pyinstaller` command should be run in the command prompt or terminal**.

Here's how you can run the `pyinstaller --onefile` command:

1. Open the command prompt or terminal on your computer.
2. Navigate to the directory where your Python script is located using the `cd` command. For example, if your Python script is located in `C:\Users\Username\Documents\Python Scripts`, you would run the following command: `cd C:\Users\Username\Documents\Python Scripts`
3. Once you're in the directory with your Python script, run the `pyinstaller --onefile scriptname.py` command. Replace `scriptname.py` with the name of your Python script.
4. PyInstaller will create a `dist` directory containing the executable file.

   The `--onefile` option specifies that PyInstaller should bundle the script into a single executable file.

   If your script requires additional files or modules, you can use PyInstaller's `--add-data` and `--hidden-import` options to include them.

   For example: `pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "path/to/data:data" --hidden-import "module_name" script.py`

   This command tells PyInstaller to include the file at "path/to/data" as a data file and to import "module_name" as a hidden module.
5. Test the executable by running it from the command line: `./dist/scriptname`

   Replace `scriptname` with the name of your executable file.

   If your script requires command line arguments, pass them after the executable name.

   For example: `./dist/scriptname arg1 arg2`

   This will run the script with "arg1" and "arg2" as the command line arguments.

Hope this will help in future, the question was asked 2yrs 8 months ago